# Browse Ubuntu apps from command-line

Tags: command-line, software-center

I can browse Ubuntu Softwares in Gnome-Software. And they are catagorised very well . I am looking for a CLI version of this. That is, I would like to browse apps from terminal where I could list all apps under a specific category (say games) .

[image]

*Why am I looking for this ?*

If I could could browse apps from terminal, The search results could be highly customized using tools like `grep` , `awk` etc...

Comment: i think their's no direct solution but you can change the xml files to what you need on java i use **Document**  to xml files anyway go to gnome software directory `cd /usr/share/gnome-software/modulesets.d/` and list then open using terminal file you want for example `xmllint --format popular.xml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There already exists command `apt-cache dumpavail` which will list all available packages from all enabled repositories. Behind the scenes it actually reads from files stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` directory (I've done `strace` of the command, and that's what the output shows) . My guess would be that Gnome Software parses those very same files and organizes those into categories.

Problem is that the actual data has lines that start with `Package:` for package names and `Section:` to which they belong, but `Section:` lines are not organized exactly the same as in Gnome Software.  However, with a little bit of command line magic, we can come close to something like that. What I propose is a function

```
filter_sections()
{
  apt-cache dumpavail | \
  awk -v SEARCH="$@" '/^Package:/{ PKG=$0  }\
    /Section:/ && $0~SEARCH {printf PKG" "$0"\n"}'
}
```

With that function we can list all packages by sections, for instance:

```
$ filter_sections web | head                                                   
Package: apache2 Section: web
Package: awstats Section: web
Package: curl Section: web
Package: heat-api Section: web
Package: heat-api-cfn Section: web
Package: heat-api-cloudwatch Section: web
Package: heat-common Section: web
Package: heat-engine Section: web
Package: javascript-common Section: web
Package: libapache2-mod-apparmor Section: web
```

The code itself is fairly simple: we pass on the output of `apt-cache dumpavail` to `awk` which stores every package name into a varialbe , and if the `Section:` line also contains a string that we are matching, we will print both package name and the section.

As for listing the sections themselves, it's fairly easy as well

```
apt-cache dumpavail | awk '/Section:/' | sort | uniq
```

What is also nice about this approach is that some of the `Sections` mention which repository the package belongs to, for example `universe/python` or `multiverse/web` . The function , however, will search for all and of them , but if so desired we can always filter with `awk` even more

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `aptitude`.
If this is not installed in your system, go ahead and open a terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install aptitude` then `sudo aptitude` to start it.

If you want to search and filter results with `grep`, you can use either `sudo apt-cache search` or `sudo aptitude search`

Comment: I have `aptitude` installed.  But can I list all Audio apps or all games using aptitude ? If yes, I don't know how to do that, It would be nice if you include them in your answer.

Comment: You can. Both 'sound' and 'games' categories seem to exist in aptitude. If the categories are not available to you, try running a `sudo aptitude update` or press `u` while in the aptitude ncurses interface